# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not knownfailed?

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to connect to host on mac using MAMP I get this error

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname 
provided, or not knownfailed
```

This is my php code.

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1”,”pks”,”sonisoni123”,”GDRS");
    Echo mysqli_connect_error();
    if($con)
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed";
    }


    ?>
```

I don't know where I am going wrong any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is mysql running?

Comment: Have you tried using 'localhost' as hostname?

Comment: Yes.mysql running.

Comment: Yes I have used localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna switch your quote types around the connection variable; they aren't the exact same (even though they are similar), which could cause PHP to read the strings differently.

Try this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","pks","sonisoni123","GDRS");
Echo mysqli_connect_error();
if($con)
{
    echo "success";
}
else
{
    echo "failed";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One more reason why you are getting this error is you might have commented below line to your hosts file or you don't have this line.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

if you are using Mac go to `/etc/hosts` and add or uncomment `127.0.0.1 localhost` line.
This might fix your problem